# How to display TimeSpan on 30 minute intervals

Tags: c#, timespan

I have an array of timespans that are in 15 minute intervals, e.g.:

> 00:00:00,
>
> 00:15:00,
>
> 00:30:00,
>
> 00:45:00,
>
> 01:00:00

etc.

I want to loop through and only show those which are of a 30 minute interval. I've tried using the `.compare` but this doesn't get exactly what I need.

For example:

```
var interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
foreach(var t in MyArray)
{
    if(TimeSpan.Compare(inteval, t.Time) == 0)
        Do something
    }
}
```

This technically works, but would only match `00:30:00`. I can add the interval to the loop and use something like:

```
var interval = new TimeSpan(t.Hour, 30, 0)
```

but that only gets `00:30:00`, `01:30:00`.

Is there as way to make the hour like a wildcard and get every 30 min?

The output I'd want is:

> 00:00:00
>
> 00:30:00
>
> 01:00:00
>
> 01:30:00

etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want is a modulo operation, but since TimeSpans themselves don't define that, use `TotalMinutes` (or another property) to get a plain integer and then use modulo:

```
if ((int)t.TotalMinutes % 30 == 0)
```

Comment: That works, thanks.  You know if it is possible to do this in linq to entities somehow in the where clase?  I tried to do in the query rather than in a view but says not supported in linq to entities.

Comment: What data type are you using to store TimeSpans in the database?

Comment: The column is defined as Time.  I tried something like:

    _timeShiftRepository.QueryWithNoTracking.OrderBy(x => x.TimeShiftName).Where(x => (int)x.TimeShiftName.TotalMinutes % 30 == 0).ToList()

Comment: @Jeff: You might be able to get it to work by saying `t.Minutes == 0 || t.Minutes == 30`. It should translate into `DATEPART` and comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

You can also filter your array for every second item .. then use the new array and print is sequentially:

```
var newArray = MyArray.Where((t, index) => index % 2 == 0).ToArray();
```

This gives you every second item in the list.